# IDbConnection.BeginTransaction on GUI thread, using async/await, causing dead-lock with multiple calls

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, transactions, async-await

I'm having an issue, which I fully understand, but am struggling to solve.

1. I have an event loop that uses `async`/`await`.
2. I use `async`/`await` on all database operations, with continuations all landing all the same single thread that is running the event loop.
3. I also need to use transactions, which during its lifetime, will have some other continuations.

With that said, consider this code.

```cs
public async Task UpdateItem(int mediaItemId)
{
    using (var connection = _dataService.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var item = await connection.SingleByIdAsync<MediaItem>(mediaItemId);

            item.Index++;
            await connection.UpdateAsync(item);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

The caller of this method is originating from the main event loop.

I begin by creating a transaction. Using SqlLite, this is effectively a database-level mutex. This means that while a transaction is on-going, other calls to `BeginTransaction` will block.

Now, consider that this method is called multiple times, in quick succession. After `await`ing `SingleByIdAsync`, the second call will attempt to `BeginTransaction`, but it will wait there until the first transaction is complete. This is expected, except that it will block the main event loop, preventing any further continuations from happening, leaving the first transaction to be left open.

Boom, deadlock.

This would be solved if there was a `IDbConnection.BeginTransactionAsync`, which there isn't. That would I could jump of the event loop, and continue once the transaction succeeds in opening.

So, consider the following fix:

```cs
public async Task UpdateItem(int mediaItemId)
{
    using (var connection = _dataService.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        // Note that we are awaiting the opening of the transaction.
        using (var transaction = await Task.Run(() => connection.BeginTransaction()))
        {
            var item = await connection.SingleByIdAsync<MediaItem>(mediaItemId);

            item.Index++;
            await connection.UpdateAsync(item);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

With that said, do you see any harm in opening a transaction of a thread that didn't open the database connection? Why isn't there a `IDbConnection.BeginTransactionAsync`? Is `await Task.Run(() => connection.BeginTransaction())` an acceptable solution?

Comment: Can you show the "event loop"? .NET normally does not have such a thing, at least not in the way it is suggested here.

Comment: It's glib-based. It's hard to describe, but I'm using QmlNet

Comment: Please find a way to convey the essence of the situation. Is there one thread with a synchronization context?

Comment: Yes, one thread, with an event loop, with a custom synchronization context that dispatches continuations onto the event loop that is running on the single thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With that said, do you see any harm in opening a transaction of a thread that didn't open the database connection?

There's a couple of considerations here. The first one is opening a transaction on a different thread than the one that opened the db connection. Another is that you're commiting and disposing the transaction on a different thread than the one that opened it.

> Is await Task.Run(() => connection.BeginTransaction()) an acceptable solution?

The question of "is this a problem?" can only be answered by your (client) database provider.

If you want to be sure that it won't be a problem, you can include your own mutex:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public async Task UpdateItem(int mediaItemId)
{
  using (var connection = _dataService.OpenDbConnection())
  {
    await _mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
      using (var transaction = await connection.BeginTransaction())
      {
        var item = await connection.SingleByIdAsync<MediaItem>(mediaItemId);
        item.Index++;
        await connection.UpdateAsync(item);

        transaction.Commit();
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      _mutex.Release();
    }
  }
}
```

Or, [using AsyncEx for a nicer syntax](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/5.0.0-pre-05/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.SemaphoreSlimExtensions):

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public async Task UpdateItem(int mediaItemId)
{
  using (var connection = _dataService.OpenDbConnection())
  using (_mutex.LockAsync())
  using (var transaction = await connection.BeginTransaction())
  {
    var item = await connection.SingleByIdAsync<MediaItem>(mediaItemId);
    item.Index++;
    await connection.UpdateAsync(item);

    transaction.Commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just looked at the .NET sqlite implementation, particularly ```sqlite3_exec```, and it is thread-safe. I am going to just await on a different thread.